# Volume bounded by the regions $y= \frac{1}{x}, x=1, x=2, y= 0$ about $x= 3$ using the shell method

Tags: integration, volume

Find volume by these bounded regions $y=\dfrac{1}{x}, x=1, x=2, y= 0$ about $x= 3$ (shell method)

Not sure what is wrong with my integral here.

$$2\pi \int_1^2 \frac{(3-x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x+ \frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 3-x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2pi+%28+integral+1+to+2+of+%283-x%29%281%2Fx%29+%2B+integral+1+to+2+of+%283-x%29%281%2F2%29

It does not match up with the answer, $6\pi \ln 2 - 2\pi$

I split it up into two integral sincet here are two heights, one shape is like a rectangle another is a curvature.

Comment: It is hard to guess that "about" mean "when rotated around the line".  Even harder is to guess why your sum should give something related to the volume we want to compute.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the first integral I wrote is the answer? I thought the height changes from x to 1/2. Thus we need two integrals? How would this problem change if the axis of rotation was y =3?

Comment: EDIT: yay i figured it out after carefully reviewing the graph. Can i get any hints on how to start on the disk method or this problem?

Comment: I keep getting this for disks -_- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+*+%28integral+1%2F2+to+1+of+%283-1%2Fy%29%5E2+-1+%2B+integral+0+to+1%2F2+%283%29%29

Answer (score 0):

If you used the disc method, you would need to break the region up into two pieces. However, applying the shell method allows you to use a single region here.

For a given shell, the radius of the annular region is $3-x$ and the height is $1/x$, so

$dV = h \cdot 2\pi r \cdot dr = \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot 2\pi (3-x) dx = 2\pi\ \Big(\dfrac{3}{x} - 1\Big) dx$

So

$I = 2\pi \displaystyle\int\limits_{1}^{2}{\Big(\dfrac{3}{x} - 1}\Big) dx = 2\pi \Big[3\ln{|x|}-x\Big]_{x=1}^{x=2} = 2\pi\ (3\ ln{\ 2}-1)$